# How to make a shorter ternary conditional operator in a React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I made a countdown timer in React using useState and useEffect hooks; everything is working great however the ternary conditional operator for seconds, where I am prepending `0` and replacing the counter value 0 with `00` for display purposes seems a bit excessive. Is there a way to simplify/shorten this, maybe setting `Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)` to a variable in the `return ()`? Not sure how to do this in React.

```
return (
  <div className={styles.timer}>
    <span className={styles.minutes}>
      {Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))}
    </span>
    <span className={styles.colon}>:</span>
    <span className={styles.seconds}>
      {Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60)) / 1000) === 0 ?
      `00` :
      Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60)) / 1000) < 10 ?
      `0${Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)}` :
      Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)
      }
    </span>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn it into a string, then `.padStart` with `'0'` to 2 characters.

```
<span className={styles.seconds}>
  {
    String(Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60)) / 1000))
      .padStart(2, '0')
  }
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply move this logic in some some function and call that function here.

```
handleCounter = (counter) => {
  let floorValue = Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)
  if(floorValue < 10){
    return '0' + floorValue
  } else {
    return '' + floorValue
  }
}
return (
  <div className={styles.timer}>
    <span className={styles.minutes}>
      {Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60))}
    </span>
    <span className={styles.colon}>:</span>
    <span className={styles.seconds}>
      {this.handleCounter(counter)}
    </span>
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bit excessive too.
You won't be able to define the variable in the return method, instead you can solve that problem in this way.
You can add state `count` which has the value of `Math.floor((counter % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)`

So the component would be like this

```
function Timer () {
  const [ counter, setCounter ] = useState(0)
  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    var timer

    setTimeout(timer = function () {
      setCounter(counter + 1000)
      setCount(Math.floor(((counter + 1000) % (1000 * 60)) / 1000))
    }, 1000)
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  }, [counter])

  return (
    <div style={{color: 'white'}}>
      <span>
        {Math.floor(count / 60)}
      </span>
      <span>:</span>
      <span>
        {count === 0 ?
        `00` :
        count < 10 ?
        `0${count}` :
        count
        }
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Hope this is useful for you..